# Yii2 action Create

Tags: yii2

Делал Crud, для создания используется акшин Create , для редактирования Update
они рендерят один и тот же _form.php, как понять что сейчас в форме - создание или обновление, может в моделе что то передается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#$isNewRecord-detail

Если данное свойство true, то создание, false - обновление, соответственно

```
$model->isNewRecord
```

Comment: Hekumok -> Спасибо